# Lookup algorithms for lists-in-lists that are better than O(n²) complexity

Tags: java, lookup

I'm using java 1.6.
I have a set of items, and each item has a name and a set of components. each component also has a name.

```
Set<Item>

Class Item
    String name
    Set<Component>

Class Component
    String name
```

I'm now tasked with writing a method with input: item name + component name, and output: does this pair exist in the list of items.

```
public boolean hasItemComponentPair(String itemName, String componentName)
{
    for(Item item : getItems())
    {
        if (item.getName() == itemName)
        {
            for(Component component : item.getComponents())
            {
                if (component.getName() == componentName)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The easiest way to do is by simply going through the elements of the sets one-by-one, and break if a match is found. This approach is doable for small sets.

My set of items is typically between 5 and 20 items, and the set of components is about the same. So there's between 25 and 400 unique item-component pairs. This amount of pairs seems too large for the naive algorithm to be efficient, especially if the method is called several times. But I also  think a divide and conquer technique is too verbose for the given amount of elements.

What data structures and algorithms are typically used for this problem, keeping in mind the giving size of the sets?

Comment: What is the comparator of Set<Item> and Set<Component>?

Comment: Strictly with a `Set`, I don't think there's an alternative to the double loop since you have to iterate through the elements. Even with 400 possibilities, it's going to be pretty fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change your Item class you can do it like that:

```
class Item {
    String name;
    Map<String, Component> components; 
}
```

In the map above key is the name of component.

Than change your code to:

```
public boolean hasItemComponentPair(String itemName, String componentName)
{
    for(Item item : getItems())
    {
        if (item.getName().equals(itemName))
        {
            return item.getComponents().containsKey(componentName);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now you need to traverse only one collection.

Answer (score 2):

1) Sort the lists and do binary search on them.

2) Build indexes (typically as hashtable).

Comment: There's no order in Set data structure. Your first technique won't work in this scenario. Although it will be useful if there are Lists of items.

Comment: Original poster said "list", not "set", though I grant they seem to have a set of ... lists? ... in their example.

Comment: I can't see any edit on the question, so your premise seems to be wrong. ;) The question always had `Set` of `Item`s and not `List`s. :D

Answer (score 1):

Override the equals and hashCode method in your Item and Component classes like following:

```
// Item.java
import java.util.Set;

public class Item
{
  private String name;
  private Set<Component> components;

  public Item(String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode()
  {
    return name.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj)
  {
    if (obj instanceof Item)
    {
      Item item = (Item) obj;
      if (item.name != null && this.name != null)
        return item.name.equals(this.name);
    }
    return false;
  }

  public Set<Component> getComponents()
  {
    return components;
  }

  public void setComponents(Set<Component> components)
  {
    this.components = components;
  }
}

// Component.java
public class Component
{
  private String name;

  public Component(String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode()
  {
    return name.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj)
  {
    if (obj instanceof Component)
    {
      Component component = (Component) obj;
      if (component.name != null && name != null)
        return component.name.equals(this.name);
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

This will give you constant time lookup. So you can search for elements in constant time.

Following is a demonstration:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class SearchDemo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Item item1 = new Item("Item 1");
    item1.setComponents(new HashSet<Component>());
    item1.getComponents().add(new Component("Component A"));
    item1.getComponents().add(new Component("Component B"));
    item1.getComponents().add(new Component("Component C"));

    Item item2 = new Item("Item 2");
    item2.setComponents(new HashSet<Component>());
    item2.getComponents().add(new Component("Component X"));
    item2.getComponents().add(new Component("Component Y"));
    item2.getComponents().add(new Component("Component Z"));

    HashSet<Item> items = new HashSet<>();
    items.add(item1);
    items.add(item2);

    // Input from user
    String inputItem = "Item 2";
    String inputComponent = "Component Y";

    // Cast it to item and component
    Item searchItem = new Item(inputItem);
    Component searchComponent = new Component(inputComponent);

    if (items.contains(searchItem)) // Constant time search
    {
      System.out.println("Contains Item");
      for (Item item : items)
      {
        if (item.equals(searchItem))
        {
          if (item.getComponents().contains(searchComponent)) // Constant time search
          {
            System.out.println("Contains even the component");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The only issue is the for loop in the above lookup.
The item can be searched in constant time, but it has to be searched for again in the set (if it really exists) because I kind of fooled the program into believing that the `searchItem` is equal to the `item` in the set. Once the item is really found and its component set is extracted from it, its a constant time search for the `componentItem`.
If you have a `HashMap` of `Component`s in the `Item` class, instead of the `Set`, and each key in the `HashMap` is the `name` of the `component`, then the input from the user can be searched in constant time!

Comment: author has only componentName in his function. If you want to use contains from HashSet you need to pass whole Component object in this case. If Component object consists of more than componentName field and equals method uses some of those fields you can't use HashSet in this case.

Comment: I've tried and tested this program. If you see the demonstration carefully then I have created a Component out of the componentName, which I have then passed to the contains method of HashSet. Since my hashCode and equals method in Component do their work only with the `name` variable, this technique works and will work even if Component class has hundred more variables.

Comment: Yes that's right but I'm not sure if author gave us whole Component class. Probably not because you don't really need a class with 1 String field. If you have more fields in Component class which are used in equals method than you can't use your solution having only componentName.

Comment: That's why I'm using only `name` in the `equals` and `hashCode` method. Its my assumption that a `Component` can be uniquely identified by its `name` which is a fair enough assumption, because a `componentName` will be checked to see if the particular `Component` exists in the `Set` of the particular `item` or not.

Comment: What a detailed answer, thanks for that. I see hashmaps are the way to go. I have the luxury of changing my set<item> to map<string, item> so that will be easier for me.

Comment: @Awfully Awesome if you assume that it's ok

Comment: @user1884155: Then you can really have constant time lookup. :)

Comment: @JakubHr: Still thanks for mentioning it in the comments so that others who don't know can know about it.